# Rigor in elementary number theory

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $a$ and $n$ be natural numbers with $(a,n) = 1$. Then $(a^j,n) = 1$ for any natural number $j$. I am aware that the proofs on this site use induction, the binomial theorem, or that relatively prime numbers can be written as $ax + by = 1$. However, I "proved" this myself without these since I didn't see why I really needed to use them. It seems like the most obvious way to prove it and so I guess there must be a good reason why the answers on here didn't use it.

If $(a,n) = 1$ then $a = p^{r_1}_1 \cdot \cdot \cdot p^{r_k}_k$ where each $p$ is prime. We have that $a^j = p^{jr_1}_1 \cdot \cdot \cdot p^{jr_k}_k$ which is clearly a product of the same primes of $a$ with the only difference being that  each prime is raised to the $jth$ power. Hence $(a^j,n) = 1$.

Comment: You have the right idea but some gaps. Firstly what if $a=1$ (a simple case but not covered by your reasoning). Secondly you have to also mention that $\gcd(p_i,n)=1$ and $r_i \geq 1$ otherwise you can't make the final claim. BTW you are using uniqueness of prime factorization etc. so you too are using some well-known results which (may) require induction etc. for their proofs.

Comment: My goal wasn't to not use induction, but it didn't seem at all required for the problem to write a proof of this specific result using it. I am aware that the proofs of the results I am using might require it, however.

Comment: Doesn't your second point come directly from the definition of relatively prime numbers? That's why I didn't mention it.

Comment: It does, but when you write a proof you have to give a reasoning to support your claims and maintain the flow. Otherwise there are two statements, that $\gcd(a,n)=1$ and $a$ has a prime factorization. Both of them are fine on their own but how are they related is what you need to bring out.

Comment: Alright it is clear to me now I should have put that connecting idea in my first sentence after the prime factorization. I have never been the best writer...Thanks.

Comment: Your proof relies on the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (FTA; the existence *and* uniqueness of a prime factorization).  The existence part of the FTA is usually proved by induction, while the uniqueness typically relies on something like Euclid's lemma, which is a consequence of Bezout's lemma (though more elementary proofs exist).  Thus when you invoke the FTA, you are sweeping a lot of theory under the rug.  Assuming that you have not used your result to prove FTA, this is fine, but it might be helpful to trace the ideas and see what you are relying on.

Comment: And so is it suggested that I start trying to use the "weakest" results I know first? FTA was proved in this book two chapters ago, but I guess it is overkill and such a practice might lead to not really understanding the material, but only applying theorems.

Comment: "Weakest" is relative, as there are often multiple paths which lead to the development of a theory.  For example, in analysis (the area with which I am most familiar), measure theory can be proved from the point of view of set functions on a $\sigma$-algebra, or from the point of view of bounded linear operators on an appropriate function space.  If one starts from the point of view of set functions, certain results in functional analysis can be proved via the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem.  However, these results are provable from "weaker" theorems on the functional side.

Comment: However, if one develops the theory from the point of view of set functions, it might be easier to invoke the deep theorem of Riesz, Markov, and Kakutani to avoid a lot of tedious and redundant work.

Comment: @DerekLuna: Your answer is correct. Ideas are important and this is the type of thinking process that is needed to solve problems. Other commenters aim is to guide you you through precision.

Comment: Since you mention "rigor", another point is worth emphasis. This can fail in domains where factorizations into irreducibles is not unique, so the proof must use uniqueness. But you never invoke it (though you likely implicitly use it). Such invocations should be *explicit* in order for the proof to be *rigorous*.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a little bit of a [frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge). Based on the title of the question and some of the comments posted below the question, it seems that the correct question is something like:

> **Theorem 1:**  Suppose that $a$ and $n$ are natural numbers such that $(a,n)=1$.  Then we have $(a^j,n) = 1$ for any natural number $j$.
>
> **Question:** Is there an elementary proof of Theorem 1?  Is a proof via the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic more elementary?

In addition to this question (which seems to be hinted at in the title, there also seems to be a secondary question, which is

> Is my proof, which uses the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, correct?

The second question is easier to answer:  your proof is fundamentally (heh heh) correct, if a little imprecise.  Other commenters have pointed out how you could improve precision, and I suspect that one of them may provide an answer, so I am going to ignore this question.  To me, the first question is more interesting, anyway.

To answer this first question, we need to agree on what is meant by an "elementary" proof.  By an elementary proof, I mean a proof which depends on the smallest number of theorems (where both "smallest number" and "theorem" are somewhat nebulously defined).  Elementary proofs are often actually quite a bit harder than more "advanced" proofs, because you have to get your hands dirty and actually work the details out—the goal is to *avoid* invoking theorems so that you can actually see how the argument proceeds.  This can make things harder, as the proof may become more convoluted.  Analyzing proofs of Theorem 1, I see the following:

#### A standard proof

The proof of Theorem 1 with which I am most familiar is by induction and uses some moderately powerful theorems for the base case.  The proof of the base case is roughly the proof given on [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Square_of_Coprime_Number_is_Coprime), which depends on something like Bezout's theorem somewhere down the line.  I would argue that this proof is relatively elementary:  it depends chiefly on the Principle of Mathematical Induction (which is a big theorem), and either a tedious elementary argument or an application of Bezout (or something similar).  Let's call this two big theorems.

#### Proof via the FTA

On the other hand, your proof is a relatively direct application of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (FTA).  The FTA has two pieces:  an existence bit, and a uniqueness bit.  The existence bit is usually proved via the Principle of Mathematical Induction or via the Well Ordering Principle (which is equivalent to the Principle of Mathematical Induction)—both of our proofs require this particular "big theorem".

The uniqueness bit can be proved in a number of ways:  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Proof) offers two proofs, one of which is elementary (-ish... it also seems to depend on the Well Ordering Principle), and the other of which relies on Euclid's lemma, which in turn is typically proved with Bezout's Lemma.  [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Prime_Decomposition_of_Integer_is_Unique) gives another proof, which relies on something it calls the Fundamental Theorem of Equivalence relations, which seems like a "big theorem" to me (it is called "fundamental", after all, and the proof requires some work).  In any event, proving the FTA seems to require at least two "big theorems", if not more, and then you have to actually invoke the FTA to prove Theorem 1.

#### Conclusion

By this analysis, I would argue that one "needs" induction to prove Theorem 1 (either directly, or in the proof of the FTA, or in the proof of the FTA via the Well-Ordering Principle).  Bezout's lemma is likely unnecessary, though it seems that some weakened form of Bezout is probably required.  Invoking the FTA doesn't seem to get around this, but does sweep it under the rug a bit.